# Angularjs datatable how to render table after the ajax call

Tags: php, angularjs, datatable, angular-datatables

I got a project require angularjs datatable (i-lin) to populate large amount of data. Therefore, i decided to use **server side processing** and Ajax call to get my PHP data populate into the angularjs datatable. Currently, i could show the static columns and data perfectly however.......

**Problem**

> The Ajax(api call) needs sometime to request the data therefore now my page will show the static data columns first. A few seconds later, page will refresh again then append the new columns. 
>       Which means, user will see the static datatable columns first, After 1 second will see another datatable. It looks very weird for user.

**Target**

> Instead of show the static columns, I would like ensure all data has been returned from Ajax then only show the complete table.

**Code**

html

```
<table id="saleReport"
       class="report-table table-striped table table-bordered
              table-condensed table-hover data-table"
       datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns"
       dt-instance="dtInstance">
```

Angularjs
The **Module.fetchSalesData** are API call from the PHP

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder
    .newOptions()
    .withOption('ajax',  function (data, callback, settings) {
        // set dataSrc

        settings.sAjaxDataProp = 'trans';

        Module.fetchSalesData({
            draw: data.draw,
            length: data.length,
            start: data.start,
            search : data.search.value,
            count_again : $scope.countAgain,
            startdate: $filter('date')($scope.item.startdate, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
            enddate : $filter('date')($scope.item.enddate, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
            payee_id: $scope.item.payee_id,
            staff_id: $scope.item.staff_id,
            order: data.order
        }).then(function(res) {
            $scope.payment_methods = res.data;

            callback(res);
            $scope.countAgain = false;
        })
     })
  .withOption('serverSide', true)


//This is static dtColumns, User will see this first
$scope.dtColumns = [
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('invoice_date')
    .withTitle('Date')
    .withOption('sWidth', '10%'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('ref_num').withTitle('Description')
];
```

```
//Set timout waiting server returned **$scope.payment_methods** 
//in order to generate dtcolumns dynamically 
setTimeout(function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.payment_methods, function (value) {
        $scope.dtColumns.push(
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(value).withTitle(value)
            .notSortable().withClass('text-right')
            .withOption('stateSave', true)
            .renderWith(function (data, type, full) {
                data = typeof data === 'undefined' ? '0.00' : data;
                return $filter('currency')(data, '');
            }),
        )
    });
}, 1000);
```

**Tried**
What i have try is using destroy the first table and keep the latest table but it failed

```
var table = $('#saleReport').DataTable();
table.clear().destroy();
```

Appreciated of you guys could give me the ideas.

Comment: The `setTimeOut` API is not integrated with the AngularJS framework. Instead, use the $timeout service. AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Comment: Try this $('#saleReport).DataTable().ajax.reload(); in .then of Module.fetchSalesData.

Comment: @georgeawg Thanks for the advise. Already changed it. And I trying to implement the promise for the Ajax call.

Comment: @Supercool. It still the same. Is it possible to delay the dtOption until the Ajax data is fully returned then only show the table?

Comment: I moved the static and dynamic columns into the `.then(function)` but i get the error `Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined`